# Using Logical Operators in One Line

Tags: functions, logic

I am looking for a function that has this meaning:

```
f(x)= if x>10 x+1 else x-1
```

or

```
f(x)=x>10 : x+1 ? x-1
```

Similar to the ternary operator in computer programming. What syntax should I use to express this as a mathematical function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall x [(x>10 \rightarrow f(x) = (x + 1))] \land \forall x[(x\leq 10 \rightarrow f(x) = x-1)]$

I saw the "logic" tag, and assumed you wanted a means to express this in logic.

Essentially, there are two cases: 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x+1 &\text{ if}\; x>10\\ \\ x-1 &\text{ if}\; x\leq10\end{cases}$$

This is a perfectly legitimate mathematical function, known as a [***Piecewise Function***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise).

Comment: Nice reference too +1

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), defined for a predicate $P$, as
$$
[P] =\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }P\text{ is true,}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then for your function you'd have 
$$
f(x)=x-1+2[x>10]
$$
This notation comes from the programming language APL. The only downside to this notation is that a fair number of mathematicians haven't been exposed to it, so you'll have to explain it before you use it.

Comment: That's assuming I'm a mathematician.

Comment: @user1919496 Actually, from your use of the compound conditional, I had assumed you were coming from the CS side.